# regex to get $_GET variables

Tags: php, regex

I have a URL string and would like to extract parts of the URL. I have been trying to do understand how to do it with regex but no luck.

http://www.example.com?id=example.id&v=other.variable

From the example above I would like to extract the id value ie. example.id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're not referring to actual `$_GET` variables, but to a string containing a URL with a query string.

PHP has built-in functions to process those:

- [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the query string from a URL
- [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to split the query string into its components

Answer (score 4):

No need for regexp here, just use php built in function [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com?id=example.id&v=other.variable';
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $vars);
```